# Frontend Customer Session Expire But Product Price Not Update in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, price, customer-session

In my site back-end, I have created one product with price $75.00.

Also, I have set the 'Wholesale' customer group price is $50.00.

After saving the product I saw the front-end that product price shown $75.00.

I have created one 'Wholesale' customer and logged-in.

Now shown product price is $50.00.

After some hours the customer session has expired, Now click my account page redirect to customer login page.

But the product view page showing only $50.00 (Wholesale price).

Also the product list page too (Shown $50.00 Wholesale price).

How to rectify this ..? Help me.

Comment: do you have a full page cache enabled?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis I have enabled the backend cache only. I didn't used any third party cache plugin.

Comment: Reindex, then clear your `cache/*`, `full_page_cache/*` and `session/*` folders.

Comment: @bluemwhitew I have tried but its not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the **NOT LOGGED IN** customer group price is $50.00 (Same as the product normal price).

After that its working fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to disable Magento's cache?

In one of my projects, I have experienced some issues on Magento's cache. After disabling it, I activate the Redis cache, which reduces so much the loading time.

Hope it helps.